Percona Xtra backup -File ./ib_logfile0: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
Is there any way to solve this error?
xtrabackup --backup --user=backupuser2 --password='pass' --target-dir=/u02/backup/
xtrabackup: recognized server arguments: --server-id=1 --log_bin=mysql-bin.log --innodb_log_file_size=1G --datadir=/opt/data --log_bin=/opt/data/mysql-bin.log 
xtrabackup: recognized client arguments: --target-dir=/u02/backup/ --backup=1 --target-dir=/u02/backup/ --user=backupuser2 --password=* 
xtrabackup version 8.0.4 based on MySQL server 8.0.13 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: c2c0777)
240416 11:19:51  version_check Connecting to MySQL server with DSN 'dbi:mysql:;mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup' as 'backupuser2'  (using password: YES).
240416 11:19:51  version_check Connected to MySQL server
240416 11:19:51  version_check Executing a version check against the server...
240416 11:19:51  version_check Done.
240416 11:19:51 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: backupuser2, password: set, port: not set, socket: not set
Using server version 8.0.33
xtrabackup: uses posix_fadvise().
xtrabackup: cd to /opt/data
xtrabackup: open files limit requested 0, set to 1024
xtrabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_home_dir = .
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_file_size = 1073741824
Number of pools: 1
Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
File ./ib_logfile0: 'open' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation


Any news how to fix that?
